# Generate pdf from html

Tags: java, scala, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a simple solution of how to generate pdf from html template preferably in Scala (it could be a Java library as well). Just for information, I need to use it in a Web application made by Play Framework or Lift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for Java, free as long as you don't use it for commercial purposes. http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: does it support Unicode? I need to use Cyrillic alphabet for it.

Comment: Yes it does, check http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=198 and http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=199

Comment: can I create a table from its html code by itextpdf?

Answer (score 1):

yes itext is a nice library for starting learning about text to pdf conversion and the reverse.

Comment: does it support Unicode? I need to use Cyrillic alphabet for it.

Comment: can I create a table from its html code?